# Strange order of elements in SwiftUI with .swipeActions

Tags: swiftui

In the following code I would have expected the order of the swipe elements.
***"leading", "trailing"***.

```
struct SwipeExperiment: View {
  var body: some View {
    List{
      Text("Line 1")
      Text("Line 2")
        .swipeActions(edge: .trailing, allowsFullSwipe: true) {
          Button("trailing") { print("trailing")}
          Button("leading"){ print("leading")}
        }
    }
  }
}
```

In iOS it works as defined in the documentation.
In macOS the elements are displayed in the reverse order.
***"trailing","leading"***

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a SwiftUI bug.